# DirectX game engine compilation errors LNK2019 and LNK1120

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I got this error when compiling the engine using directx9.

Engine's WinMain code and debugging in x86 environment, libraries use d3d9.lib, d3dx9.lib, winmm.lib

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include"MainScene.h"

INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, INT)
{
#if _DEBUG
    AllocConsole();
    FILE * stream;
    freopen_s(&stream, "CONOUT$", "wt", stdout);
#endif
    App::GetInst()->Init(1280, 720, 1);
    SceneDirector::GetInst()->ChangeScene(new MainScene());
    App::GetInst()->Run();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the errror text, not just the numbers?

Comment: You should also mention what version of a C++ compiler and which SDKs you are building against. Direct3D 9 is legacy, and ``d3dx9`` is only available in the deprecated DirectX SDK. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directx-sdk--august-2009-) and [this blog post](https://aka.ms/dxsdk).